# In Drupal 7, how do I allow users to see their own unpublished content?

Tags: 7, nodes

[This Drupal page](http://drupal.org/node/1106606) says that for Drupal 7 to allow users to view their own unpublished content to check "view own unpublished content" in permissions.

I have this checked, yet when someone clicks on 'admin/content' it says permission denied.  Of course I don't want to give them permissions related to admin content.

Currently I have the `override node options` module enabled, and when a user unpublishes their content, they can no longer get back to it to continue editing and then publish it.

I cannot use the 'view unpublished' module as many threads suggest as it gives an entire role access to all unpublished content related to that role.

What I am leaning towards is a view. Currently I have a very good working block that allows people to view their PUBLISHED content while on their profile page. I cloned this and simply switched the filter "published: yes" to "published: no" and it won't work. I tried setting the view permission to view own unpublished content, and it will not work.

Is 'view own unpublished content' broken in D7? Drupal core says I should be able to allow users to view their own unpublished content. How can I do this without all this hakery and dependency on a 3rd party modules?

Comment: Why would users need to access `admin/content` just to view their own unpublished content? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Clive What I am trying to do is allow people to work on their content in an unpublished state (via the override node permissions module). However, once they unpublish it, they can no longer access it to continue editing it later. I thought that permission would allow them to see their own content on the content listing page, as there is no other place where they can see it.

Answer (score 3):

`view own unpublished content` permission allows just that - to see /node/%nid even if it is unpublished. Test it, I'm sure it will work.

If you want your users to be able to **list** their content, well, that's other topic. Easiest way is to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create listings filtered by authors, with filters like `is_published or author == current_user)`.

Comment: AH! I see. That clears up a LOT. Wow what a confusing permission.

Comment: To add to that, if you enable the core tracker module, you could see own content on `http://<yoursite>/user/%uid/track`. Of course, this would require appropriate permission.